# Can I integrate Paymentsense payment gateway with Carthrob?

Tags: cartthrob

I need to integrate Paymentsense with Carthrob.

Althought in the Cartthrob docs it says Paymentsense is included, I can't find it in the 'Choose your primary payment gateway' drop down list in the 'Payment Gateway Settings' admin.

The statement on the docs it says "The following payment gateways are included with CartThrob (or can be obtained by request)."

Does this mean I need to request Paymentsense integration? Anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?

Comment: Yes, check with the dev support at Paymentsense.  They have a Paymentsense gateway module for Cartthrob.